# regex condition not working on polymer paper-input, how to allow only decimal on paper input?

Tags: javascript, regex, polymer

i am trying to allow only decimal on paper-input. Below are my conditions.

should not allow e
should allow +, - Eg: -23.43 
should allow only 12 value after DOT(in decimal) eg: 107.123456789012

so i tried below regex but both not working.

```
   ^(?!-0(\.0+)?$)-?(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d{1,12})?$
    /^(?!-0(\.0+)?$)-?(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?$/

        <paper-input allowed-pattern="^(?!-0(\.0+)?$)-?(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?$">
        </paper-input>
```

the above regex only integers, its not accepting decimal. So tried below one. its working fine. But not sure how to restrict decimal. i want to allow only 12 values after DOT(decimal)

```
<paper-input  allowed-pattern="[-.\d]"> </paper-input>
```

Comment: use this `^\d+\.\d{1,12}$`

Comment: no its not working allowed-pattern="[\d+\.\d{1,12}]" . i am able to enter more 12 values in decimal @CodeManiac

Comment: You missed `$` at the end

Comment: @CodeManiac its not working on PolymerJs. even after adding $ :-/

Comment: Your regex seems perfectly valid for me. For what values does it fail?

Comment: Have you tried using `pattern=...` instead of `allowed-pattern=...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the doc](https://medium.com/@ellenaua/input-validation-in-google-polymer-293eb7f785b):

## pattern — RegEx pattern to validate input value

```
<paper-input pattern="[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}"></paper-input>

/**
* For this input “EN123456” is a valid value, 
* but "EN123456 " or " EN123456" are invalid values
* because there are extra characters 
* and value doesn't match a pattern
*/
```

## allowed-pattern — a pattern to restrict characters allowed to type in

```
// accepts letters only
<paper-input allowed-pattern="[a-zA-Z]"></paper-input>

// accepts digits only
<paper-input allowed-pattern="[0-9]"></paper-input>

// accepts nothing, because one character cannot match this pattern
<paper-input allowed-pattern="[0-9][A-Z]"></paper-input>
```

---

Just should use:

```
<paper-input pattern="^(?!-0(?:\.0+)?$)-?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d+)?$">
```

I've also change capture grops into non-capture groups, it's more efficient.

Comment: it not working. it allowing alphabets and not restricting decimal. able to enter more than 12 values on decimal  `<paper-input value="{{ _data.value }}" pattern="^(?!-0(?:\.0+)?$)-?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d+)?$"> </paper-input>` @Toto

Comment: @Munna:Then add `pattern-allowed="[0-9.-]"` in **addition** of `pattern="^(?!-0(?:\.0+)?$)-?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d+)?$"`

Answer (score 2):

**You can use this**

```
^[+-]?\d+\.\d{1,12}$
```

> Explanation

- `^` - Anchor to start of string.
- `[+-]?\d+` - Matches `+` or `-`(Both are optional) one or more number of digits.
- `\.` - Matches `.`.
- `\d{1,12}` - Matches 1 to 12 number of digits.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/boFgPI/3/)

```js
const regex = /^\d+\.\d{1,12}$/gm;
const str = `1.1
0
1.123456789123
a1223
0000.1111
1.abv
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't match `-23.43` as requested, and matches `000000.00000` that is not wanted.

Comment: @Toto agree on the first one. but i am not certain about second one op wants it or not ?

Comment: According to their regex, it doesn't match leading zeros `0123.456` and negative all zeros `-0.000` but it matches `0.000` (only 1 zero before the dot)